# How to modify the font size of the semivariogram axis?

Tags: r, plot, axis, gstat, covariogram

I used the R language to fit the semivariogram and the Gaussian model. During the drawing process, the font size of the coordinate axis was too small. The plot() function used could not adjust the font size. How can I modify the code? Here is the code.

```
library(gstat)
n <- 100  
X <- runif(n, 0, 100)
Y <- runif(n, 0, 100)
ref_exponential <- exp(runif(n, 0, 1))
data_exponential <- data.frame(X, Y, ref = ref_exponential)
coordinates(data_exponential) <- ~X + Y
variogram_model_exponential <- variogram(ref ~ 1, data_exponential)
gaussian_model_exponential <- fit.variogram(variogram_model_exponential, vgm("Gau"))
plot(variogram_model_exponential, model = gaussian_model_exponential, cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5)
```

I hope you can help me adjust the axis font size. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a basa graphics problem. You should educate yourself about the considerable difference between the grid graphics model and the base graphics model. … not to mention the fact that you have no [MCVE] or code that constructs a basis for this problem.

Comment: Set e.g. `cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5` in `plot()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've added all the codes. As a newcomer to learning R, I'm facing some challenges and struggling to identify the reasons. I would appreciate any advice you could provide. Thanks!

Comment: Effort to run that code produced `Error in coordinates(data_exponential) <- ~X + Y : 
  could not find function "coordinates<-"
Execution halted`

Comment: If you did not encounter that error it means you had another package loaded that you haven’t told us about. Need `library` calls for packages loaded.

Comment: To appropriately analyze the data, it is recommended to employ the gstat package for computing the semivariogram and subsequently model fitting using a Gaussian model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm excited to share that I discovered the solution to this question while navigating through my exploration. I successfully achieved my goal by specifying `scales = list(cex = 1.5)`. When it comes to plotting functions, changing the label size is similar to the parameter settings of `xyplot()`.